# copying files to usb flash drive overwrite it's partition table and file system formatting

Tags: usb

I created a dos partition table and fat32 file system on my flash drive. I then backed up the partition table. After I copied data to the drive using the "copy" command, the system could not read from the drive again. Gparted could not recognize it so I checked the partition table using "dd" and saw that it was messed up. I then replaced it with the back-up and gparted recognized the partition, but could not recognize the file system.

My question is what could make the system to write data on the partition table and the file system on the drive during a copy operation?

Comment: Are you sure you wrote to the USB partition (e.g. /dev/sdb1) instead of the device (e.g. /dev/sdb)?  Writing to the device would clobber the partition table, and the start of the filesystem on sdb1.

Comment: Yes I did, I used "copy " after mounting it on a directory.

Comment: You "checked the partition table using "dd"*" how?  Are you saying you copy *converted or copied* a file to the screen & perused the binary output??  The command `dd` will "convert and copy a file" (from `man dd`) so I can't see how you'd check a partition table using a conversion/copy tool.  Your question is unclear, and I'd just revert your backups, as it sounds like you've made numerous errors.

Comment: I checked the partition table using "dd if=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=1 | od -t x1z". I compared it to my backup (flash.img) and noticed they were different.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the file system was not healthy to start with. fat32 is a relatively simple file system and quite prone to corruption. Linux will never write "like that" on a partition table and over the file system.

- Be very **careful in removing an USB drive**. Always unmount in the file manager first, and wait some time before physically removing the USB drive. Most desktop environments provide a notification when the drive is fully unmounted and ready to be physically removed.
- Regularly **have the file systems on any removable drive checked**. In contrast to internal drive, there is no automatic file system check for removable drives. In practice, many drives remain unchecked for a long time. System file corruptions may be introduced and build up.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there any file system you will recommend i try?